# Conditions for a cubic interpolating polynomial to be increasing

Tags: calculus, polynomials, interpolation

Suppose 0 = $x_0$ < $x_1$ < $x_2$ < $x_3$ = 1 and 0 = $y_0$ < $y_1$ < $y_2$ < $y_3$ = 1. There exists a unique cubic polynomial $p(x)$ with $p(x_i) = y_i$. Is $p$ necessarily increasing everywhere on [0, 1]? If not, what conditions on $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$ and $y_2$ would imply $p$ is increasing?

The interpolating polynomial depends continuously on its inputs; you could see that from writing out the Lagrange form of the interpolating polynomial. When $x_1 = y_1$ and $x_2 = y_2$, the interpolating polynomial is the identity and the derivative is 1. So for some sufficiently perturbation away from $x_1 = y_1$ and $x_2 = y_2$ the derivative stays positive. It would be nice to say something more quantitative about how close the $x$'s need to be to the corresponding $y$'s.

Comment: What have you tried? Think about the heavy side function and make small adjustments to make the data increasing.

Comment: @user251257 Hea-vi-side? And I actually know your blog, OP, and some of the nice posts on numerical integration you have there.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel oh right. Thx

Comment: A place to start might be to compute a matrix norm of the inverse of $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & x_1-x_0 & x_2-x_0 & x_3-x_0 \\ 0 & 0 & (x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1) & (x_3-x_0)(x_3-x_1) \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & (x_3-x_0)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2) \end{bmatrix}$. It doesn't really matter which matrix norm you pick. Then the question is about the relationship between $\| A^{-1} y \|$ and the maximum absolute value of the derivative of the polynomial whose coefficients in the Newton basis are given in the vector $A^{-1} y$. The second part will probably be the harder problem.

Comment: In other words the second question is: if $p[c]$ is the polynomial given by taking the given Newton basis with the coefficients in the vector $c$, what is $h(\varepsilon)=\max_{\| c \| \leq \varepsilon} \max_{x \in [0,1]} |(p[c])'(x)|$? If you can find $\varepsilon^*$ given by the smallest $\varepsilon$ such that $h(\varepsilon)=1$, then $y$ within $\varepsilon^* \| A^{-1} \|^{-1}$ of $x$ will have your desired property.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the smallest $\varepsilon$ such that $h(\varepsilon) \geq 1$.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the result you get out of this might be *really* bad if the $x_i$ are highly non-uniform. Just for the norm of the inverse part, you get a norm of 200 for $x_1=0.1,x_2=0.35$. On the other hand maybe that's no surprise (crazy things can happen in the widest gap between nodes...)

Answer (score 2):

This should not be the case: Take a cubic $p(x)$ with bump and fit it into the unit square and find a counter-example after the fact.

Example: $p(x) = 3x^3-x^2-x$ and $\underline{x} = (0,0.8,0.9,1), \underline{y} = (0, 0.096,  0.477,  1)$.

Some thoughts about monotonicity: For simplicity fix the $x_i$. By Lagrange interpolation we get $$p'(x) = a (y)x^2 +b (y)x + c (y)$$
where  $a,b,c $ are linear in $y_i $.
We get the quadratic condition in $y $ for $p'$ to have no change of signs
$$ b^2 - 4ac < 0$$
Together with $y_1 = 0, y _4=1$ this forces $p $ to be increasing (even outside [0,1]).

I haven't computed examples so I'm not sure how much potential this has.

Comment: That sounds right. In the application I have in mind $x_i \approx y_i$. You could quantify that as a bound on their difference or ratio.